# Refer Foreign Key in Hibernate which doesnt have property

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have created a many-to-one mapping in hibernate. The following is the setting

```
<many-to-one name="groups"  class = "Groups" column="cgid"  unique="true" not-null="true" cascade="all"/>
```

In mysql this creates a table with another column called cgid.

```
mysql> describe CONTACT 
    -> ;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| IDCONTACT | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| FIRSTNAME | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LASTNAME  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| EMAIL     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| addressId | bigint(20)   | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| cgid      | bigint(20)   | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now, I need to query based on cgid name.

```
queryString = "from Contact where cgid = :id";
query = session.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("id", gd.getGid());
contactl = query.list();
```

Hibernate is constantly complaining about  it

```
could not resolve property: cgid of: domain.Contact [from domain.Contact c where c.cgid = :id]
```

Not sure, what could be done to resolve this problem. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Only @Entity attributes allowed in HQL, not actual DB column names. Either create a new attribute for 'cgid' (or) use a native SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Here `queryString = "from Contact where cgid = :id"` you are using HQL.cgid is database column name.You must write Contact class variable instead of cgid.And this variable must be mapped with cgid.If you use native sql query with hibernate you can use database column names but with hql can not use.